# Align two equations properly

Tags: align

I wanted to align both terms at the right between the two lines, and they were, but they wouldn't be centered between the + and the = signs :

```
(s_0 + s_p) &= &\mathfrak{D}s_0 &+& \mathfrak{D}s_p \\
&= &0 &+& b \\
&= &b. & &
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You could employ an `array` environment; see below. If it's not necessary to align the `+` symbols, a simpler solution is available using an `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\mathfrak' macro
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\usepackage{array}   % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators

\begin{document} 

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\begin{array}{cCcCc}
(s_0 + s_p) &= & \mathfrak{D}s_0 &+& \mathfrak{D}s_p \\
            &= & 0               &+& b \\
            &= & b
\end{array}
\]

\begin{align*}
(s_0 + s_p) &= \mathfrak{D}s_0 + \mathfrak{D}s_p \\
            &= 0 + b \\
            &=b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, but I'm wondering why it has to be so complicated, and why align wouldn't work directly...

Comment: @Jean-Paul - I guess everything's relative. Your code snippet looked ripe for an `array`-based solution, and I happen to be very familiar with the powerful `array` environment. It took me less than 40 seconds to come up with the `array`-based code shown above, i.e., `\usepackage{array}`, `\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}`, `\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}`, `\begin{array}{cCcCc}`, and `\end{array}`. `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}` came a bit later; it occurred to me only after I added the second, `align*`-based solution, at which point I tried to make the two solutions look more alike.